# Handling in-page javascript for each ajax-retrieved page using History.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

How do i do this in the best possible way? Unobtrusive and keep calling jquery's live method?

Assume everything has to be loaded on document.ready and on ajaxComplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) is supposed to be pretty nice. Demo [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/).

Here is [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) with demo [here](http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/) and to ajaxify your entire website with the HTML5 History API, History.js and jQuery [this snippet of code](https://gist.github.com/854622) is all you need.